# Ubuntu Supervisor command expansion in bash

Tags: bash, supervisord

I need to run a command via `supervisor` (bash on Ubuntu 18.04) that launches a parallel process with a number of cores equals to a fraction of the machine cores.

From the command line I can successfully run

```
mpiexec -np $(($(nproc)/2)) pvserver --mesa --force-offscreen-rendering
```

This works as expected. I then try to add the same command (with absolute paths) in the supervisor config file

```
cmd=mpiexec -np $(($(nproc)/2)) pvserver --mesa --force-offscreen-rendering
```

but I receive the error

```
[mpiexec@ip-172-31-16-210] HYD_pmcd_pmi_alloc_pg_scratch (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_utils.c:527): assert (pg->pg_process_count * sizeof(struct HYD_pmcd_pmi_ecount)) failed
[mpiexec@ip-172-31-16-210] HYD_pmci_launch_procs (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:108): error allocating pg scratch space
[mpiexec@ip-172-31-16-210] main (ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:340): process manager returned error launching processes
```

It seems that `mpiexec` is receiving the wrong argument. It goes without saying that everything works if I hardcode the np argument.

I have also tried with xargs, but its syntax is not very clear to me. This is what I tried

```
echo $(($(nproc)/2)) | xargs mpiexec -np {} pvserver --mesa --force-offscreen-rendering
```

but I cannot get this to work even from the command line.

Any suggestion?

Comment: cmd="mpiexec ..."  (i.e. quotes?)

Comment: Nope. I had already tried that.

Comment: Maybe the commands from the config file are `exec`-ed, and not run through a shell. Try something like `cmd=bash -c 'mpiexec -np $(($(nproc)/2)) pvserver --mesa --force-offscreen-rendering'`

Comment: Same error unfortunately

Comment: I don't understand supervisor config file. And why not just mpirun? 
`shell$ mpirun -np 4 my_parallel_application`

Comment: o maybe the $(()) expansion!